# Why is evaluate function setting a String "false" instead of a Boolean false?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jstl

I need some properties set that need to set that will be sent to my datepicker.

For some unknown the default values of changeMonth & changeYear aren't being set properly they return false as a String.

I know that the properties.changemonth is empty so it should return the Boolean false I set as default.

Anybody have any idea why it isn't working? Thanks in advance.

```
        $("#test-my-component-datepicker").datePicker({
             'dateFormat': "${not empty properties.dateformat ? properties.dateformat : 'dd/mm/yy'}",
             'showOn': "${not empty properties.showcalendar && properties.showcalendar ? 'button' : ''}",
             'buttonImage': "${not empty properties.showcalendar && properties.showcalendar ? properties.imagecalendar : ''}",
             'buttonImageOnly': "${not empty properties.showcalendar && properties.showcalendar ? properties.showbuttononly : ''}",
             'changeMonth': "${not empty properties.changemonth ? properties.changemonth : false}",
             'changeYear': "${not empty properties.changeyear ? properties.changeyear : false}",
             'showButtonPanel': false,                 
             'showOtherMonths': true,
             'selectOtherMonths': true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *empty* is a string operator (or at least operator for objects which has .isEmpty() method)
- the result of expresison is quoted, so anything it was - it is converted to string via toString()

Empty: The empty operator is a prefix operation that can be used to determine whether a value is null or empty.

```
"${not empty properties.changemonth ? properties.changemonth : false}"
"${not empty String ? String : boolean}"
"${String}"  or  "${boolean}"
"String"  or  "boolean"
String  or  Boolean.valueOf(boolean).toString()
```